# Spreadsheet calculating sum of values as per date and specific text

Tags: google-sheets

I have the following data in a Google Spreadsheet:

```
+------+------------+---------------+---------+---------+
| Date | Difficulty |               |Date     | Points  |
+------+------------+---------------+---------+---------+
| Jul15| Easy       | Easy (1pts)   |  Jul15  |4        |
| Jul15| Easy       | Medium (2pts) |  Jul16  |5        |
| Jul15| Medium     | Hard (3pts)   |         |         |
| Jul16| Hard       |               |         |         |
| Jul16| Medium     |               |         |         |
+------+------------+---------------+---------+---------+
```

I would like to add up all the points for a date in the column date/points where points for a date are next to each other. Points depend on difficulty and are in column 3.

I was able to get the dates in column 4 by using

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A800)
```

However, unable to get points 4, 5 etc in column 5. Can someone suggest how it can be done?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10FHGg68NwrYxzNxP4cXyyQModt0Dbw8aVDlby8s6dFk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can someone suggest why this is being downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Y1:Easy Z1:1
Y2:Medium Z2: 2
...

C1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({A:A,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B:B,Y:Z,2,0),B:B)},"Select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1 is not null group by Col1",1))
```

- VLOOKUP to convert "difficulty" to "points"
- QUERY  to aggregate values

Comment: This is awesome, would have never been able to reach it by me. You are an excel guru for sure. :) 

Can you pls suggest:
1. How can I change "sum Difficulty" to "points"
Thanks

Comment: Modified it using label, kept trying it with column name "AS"

Comment: @Code Yes. You can do it with `label`. Solved?